# php convert string to method call

Tags: php

```
<?php
  $str = "getList";

  //now by doing something to $str i need to call getList() method any sugesstions 

  function getList(){
    echo "get list called";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function to call the function by name.

Answer (score 6):

This feature is known as [`Variable functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), here is an example from php.net:

```
 <?php
 function foo() {
     echo "In foo()<br />\n";
 }

 function bar($arg = '')
 {
     echo "In bar(); argument was '$arg'.<br />\n";
 }

 // This is a wrapper function around echo
 function echoit($string)
 {
     echo $string;
 }

 $func = 'foo';
 $func();        // This calls foo()

 $func = 'bar';
 $func('test');  // This calls bar()

 $func = 'echoit';
 $func('test');  // This calls echoit()
 ?>
```

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable as a function name. This will execute `getList()`:

```
$str();
```

However, stuff like this is mostly a symptom of a design problem. Care to elaborate what you need this for?